# After modifying the source code editor for Manifest file on VS for Mac in Android project, the source code revert back to its original state?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, visual-studio-mac

After modifying the source code editor for Manifest file on VS for Mac in Android project, the source code revert back to its original state? How do I change it completely

I tried to put some  tags out of the application brackets, but after build the app again, it revert to its original stage.

Set up:

Visual Studio Community for Mac 2019

Comment: Hi, could you share the modified Manifest file,and point that where you need to modify? In addition, you could update the version of vs for mac to the latest to have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised the problems afterwards,
The reason is I edited the Manifest file generated by Visual Studio for Mac debug output, rather than editing the original Manifest file.
This is fixed the issue and did not revert to the original state. Thanks for your help